# Wie soll man in Bergmans "Szenen einer Ehe" den Ausdruck "Man denke" verstehen?

Tags: meaning

Ein Ausschnitt aus dem Dialog von Ingmar Bergmans Film "Szenen einer Ehe":

> Marianne: ... Willst du was zu trinken?
>
> Johan: Ja, bitte, einen Whisky könnte ich gut vertragen. Pur und ohne Eis, wenn´s geht. Das wird meinem Magen guttun. Ich meine zum Beruhigen.
>
> Marianne: Trinkst du neuerdings Whisky?
>
> Johan: Ja, man denke.

Wie eigentlich soll man diesen Ausdruck "man denke" verstehen?

Comment: "man stelle sich vor"?

Comment: I think, i think. [see](http://context.reverso.net/%C3%BCbersetzung/deutsch-englisch/%2C+man+denke)

Comment: Wie ist der Wortlaut in der originalen schwedischen Fassung?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Die originale schwedische Wortlautung sollte

> "[Ja,] tänka sig"

heißen, was ein sehr gewöhnlicher aber eher altmodischer Ausdruck ist, und genau das bedeutet, was schon von Chr. Geiselmann vorgeschlagen worden ist:

> [Ja,] stell dir vor

Die konstruktion des Ausdrucks ist etwas komisch schon auf schwedisch, und heißt wörtlich "denken sich", was ja kaum grammatisch zu verstehen ist. Das Verb denken  (tänka) ist hier in Infinitiv und man muss sich ein unausgesprochenes Hilfsverb vorstellen, etwa *mögen*, *lassen* oder vielleicht *können*, und auch ein Prädikat wie *man*, *es* oder *das* dürfte dazu. Also ist die Bedeutung genauer

> Man stelle sich vor,
>   oder
>   Man mag sich denken
>   oder vielleicht auch
>   Das lässt sich denken

Warum *sich* und nicht *dir* oder *Ihnen*?
Das hängt mit der alten Tendenz im Schwedischen, die direkte Anrede zu vermeiden zusammen. Wir sagten früher nicht gerne Sie, sondern schrieb das in dritter Person um. Herr/ Frau/ Kandidat/ Disponent/ xy usw wenn man mit einem höher in der Hierarchie redete, und nur *er* oder *sie* wenn herunter adressiert wurde. Andere Umschreibungen in Passivform  die man fast nicht übersetzen kann, waren auch sehr beliebt.

die "Direktübersetzung" im Film ist wirklich nicht gelungen, und überhaupt nicht idiomatisch.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds very odd. I believe what was meant is something like "Yes. Imagine that." Still, nothing any native German speaker would say.

Answer (score 4):

Der Wortlaut ist in der Tat ein bisschen ungewöhnlich oder hölzern. Allerdings wäre zu bedenken:

1) Wie ist der schwedische Originalwortlaut? Wird dort auch ein ungewöhnlicher, hölzerner Ausdruck verwendet, vielleicht weil dies zur Person (Johan) gehört?

2) Könnte es sein, dass typischere deutsche Ausdrücke nicht gut zur Lippenbewegung des Sprechers passen, so dass die Ansprüche guter Synchronisierung zu der Wortwahl  beitrugen?

Hier ein paar Ausdrücke, die im Deutschen typisch oder jedenfalls möglich wären:

> Marianne: Trinkst du neuerdings Whisky?
>
> Johan: Ja, denk mal.
>
> Johan: Ja, stell dir vor.
>
> Johan: Ja, da kuckst du, was?
>
> Johan: Ja, kaum zu glauben, was?
>
> Johan: Ja, es geschehen noch Zeichen und Wunder.

(Mit steigendem Sarkasmus)